# Why are the elements following the floated elements overlapping?

Tags: html, css

Working on my portfolio site, and my "About" section is three columns of text that becomes stacked for smaller screens (did this with using a media query). Now I want to add a footer section below the "About" section, but the div containing my footer is overlapping the "About" section.

This is essentially what I have, although very simplified:

```css
#about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section1 {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5% 2% 5% 5%;
  display: block;
  float: left
}

.section2 {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 5% 2% 5% 5%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.section3 {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 5%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #about {
      position: static;
  }
    .section1 { 
      float: none;
      margin-right: 5%;
      width: auto;
  }
    .section2 {
      float: none;
      margin: 15% 5% 0% 5%;
      width: auto;
  }
    .section3 {
      float: none;
      margin: 15% 5% 20% 5%;
      width: auto;
  }
}

#footer {
    width: 70%;
    height: 0%;
    margin: 0% 15% 10% 15%;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-top-color: #5f5e5f;
}
```

```html
<div id="About">
    <div class=section1>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Some Text here. This is the largest section of the three.</p>
    </div>
    <div class=section2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Some Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class=section3>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Some Text here.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer Text Here</p>
</div>
```

I am able to position the footer for desktop viewports (although it still creeps up on the "About" section on smaller screens), but I can't find a way to position it at the bottom of the page for both desktop and mobile screens.

Comment: you need to clear the **float** for your `#about`.

Comment: I apologize, I'm not quite sure how to do that. Would that be done in the media query?

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear the floats in your "About" section. You can do this by adding a `clear` declaration to your footer (I moved the `#footer` ruleset to the top to make it easier to see). This is yet another case of the clearfix hack being excessive and totally unnecessary for such a simple scenario.

```css
#footer {
    clear: both;
    width: 70%;
    height: 0%;
    margin: 0% 15% 10% 15%;
    border-top-style: solid;
    border-top-width: thin;
    border-top-color: #5f5e5f;
}

#about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.section1 {
  width: 40%;
  margin: 5% 2% 5% 5%;
  display: block;
  float: left
}

.section2 {
  width: 20%;
  margin: 5% 2% 5% 5%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

.section3 {
  width: 15%;
  margin: 5%;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    #about {
      position: static;
  }
    .section1 { 
      float: none;
      margin-right: 5%;
      width: auto;
  }
    .section2 {
      float: none;
      margin: 15% 5% 0% 5%;
      width: auto;
  }
    .section3 {
      float: none;
      margin: 15% 5% 20% 5%;
      width: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="About">
    <div class=section1>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Some Text here. This is the largest section of the three.</p>
    </div>
    <div class=section2>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Some Text here.</p>
    </div>
    <div class=section3>
        <h4>Title</h4>
        <p>Some Text here.</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer Text Here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: So it states that every-time when `#about` DOM is being used at any-page then its sibling must have this `clear: both`

Answer (score -1):

Instead of adding a new class, you can use *pseudo* elements for clearing the *float*, viz quite a popular these days as:

### CSS

```
/* A slight change in your CSS */
#about {
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
}

/* clearfix CSS for clearing the float of your child elements */
#about::after, 
#about::before { 
    content: ""; 
    display: table;
}

#about::after {
    clear: both;
}
```

For better look into, Here I have created a [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/g07verc9/2)

Comment: I wasn't the one who downvoted you, but this didn't work for me either. I might just have to deconstruct the entire thing and start from scratch.

Comment: Heh... I got hit by one too. Maybe someone just really doesn't like float layouts.

Comment: hahaha :D, there we go, Also check the fiddle, might that help you.

Comment: Looking at the fiddle, that is exactly what I need. One question: you introduced the #About (with a capital A) id, should I copy everything from the #about id and move it to #About, then remove the old #about?

Comment: Oh no, that's just a typo, my bad (-_-), have updated my answer and Fiddle both.